# offset parameter not working with jquery smoothscroll plugin

Tags: jquery

so I'm using the smoothscroll plugin which scrolls to a selector when you click on a link. My issue is it's not centering on the page when I scroll to it, so I need to offset it so that it centers:

`$('nav a').smoothScroll({offset: -191});`

Not sure what I'm missing. The site is  [seattlewebdesigner.org](http://www.seattlewebdesigner.org)  and the link says work, and goes to the #work down the page. The script is down in the footer. So to clarify I need it to scroll to -191px from where it is scrolling now. Thanks.

edit: also here is the plugin's [github.](https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll)

edit2: changed selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ahh ok so just a heads-up.. There are apparently two jquery plugins with the exact same name, so if you're having any issues with "smooth-scroll", it may be because you're modifying "smoothScroll." Anyway I'll just leave this up incase anyone has a similar issue as I did.